# using python @property in __init__ , gives attribute error

Tags: python, properties

## Is my 'fix' the correct / good practice method?

I have a class Text(), that caches it's surface to render, unless font/size changes. (I left the font property from the snippet)

### If I attempt to use `self.size` in `__init__` , it will fail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 21, in <module>
    t = Text("arial", 6)
  File "temp.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.size = size
  File "temp.py", line 16, in size
    if self._size != px:            
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute '_size'
```

I was able to assign `self._text` in `__init__` , but I believe that's wrong, since:

1. Ignores the setter, which may have extra checks
2. code might break if `_text` changes, but could be ok if it uses the
   property instead.

### Code with error:

```
class Text(object):
    def __init__(self, font, size=12):
        self.size = size
        self.font = font
        self.dirty = False

    def draw(self):
        print "Draw: ", self.size, self.font, self.dirty

    @property
    def size(self): 
        return self._size

    @size.setter
    def size(self, px):
        if self._size != px:            
            self._size = px
            self.dirty=True

if __name__  == "__main__":
    t = Text("arial", 6)
    t.draw()
    t.size = 8
    t.draw()
```

### My fix:

```
class Text(object):
    def __init__(self, font, size=12):
        self.size = size
        self.font = font
        self.dirty = False

    def draw(self):
        print "Draw: ", self.size, self.font, self.dirty

    @property
    def size(self): 
        return self._size
    @size.setter
    def size(self, px):
        try:
            if self._size != px:            
                self._size = px
                self.dirty=True
        except:
            self._size = 14
            self.dirty = True

if __name__  == "__main__":
    t = Text("arial", 6)
    t.draw()
    t.size = 8
    t.draw()
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the property during `__init__` to begin with? By definition, when you're creating a fresh instance, its attributes are new/dirty, anyway! Just set `self._size` directly during `__init__`, IMO.

Answer (score 6):

```
   try:
        if self._size != px:            
            self._size = px
            self.dirty=True
    except:
        self._size = 14
        self.dirty = True
```

The except is a bad idea because you catch all exceptions. You might accidentally catch some other exception and ignore it. That would be a bad idea. Python throws exceptions for all sorts of reason and you'll end up masking a bug. For the same reason, you should put as little code in the try block as possible.

One approach would be:

```
try:
   size_changed = self._size != size
except AttributeError:
   size_changed = True

if size_changed:
    self._size = size
    self.dirty = True
```

But a cleaner way to solve this problem:

```
def __init__(self, font, size=12):
    # store something in the hidden attribute
    # so it will work as expected
    self._size = None

    self.size = size
    self.font = font
    self.dirty = False
```

Answer (score 4):

The pattern that I use is:

```
class Text(object):
    def __init__(self, font, size=12):
        self.font = font
        self._size = size
        self.dirty = False
    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size
    @size.setter
    def size(self, px):
        if self._size != px:
            self._size = px
            self.dirty = True
```

The problem that you were running in to is that your setter was referring to an attribute that you weren't creating until the setter was called -- `self._size` doesn't exist until you have assigned something to it.  Generally, I use properties that have nice names (like `size`) and store the data in *hidden* attributes (e.g., `_size`).  In the initializer, I only manipulate the attributes directly and never rely on properties.

In your case, setting the property has a side-effect so you have a chance of bugs creeping in.  Consider what would happen if you put `self.dirty = False` as the first line in the initializer.

Comment: +1 Excellent point about the subtle importance of the ordering of the lines